# php mysql выбор данных в столбце

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите как можно выбрать значение из столбца 'route_long_name' в mysql, если есть запись в нем такого вида разделенная (-) "А.С.""КРЕСТОВСКИЙ ОСТРОВ"" - БАЛТИЙСКИЙ ВОКЗАЛ"", нужно получить для одного условия 'А.С. КРЕСТОВСКИЙ ОСТРОВ' для другого условия 'БАЛТИЙСКИЙ ВОКЗАЛ'

```
$q = "SELECT route_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,transport_type,urban,night FROM stop_bus WHERE route_id = $statement->routeId";
$res = $link->query($q);
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    $r_id = $row['route_id'];
    $rs = $row['route_short_name'];
    $rl = $row['route_long_name'];
    $rt = $row['transport_type'];
    $ur = $row['urban'];
    $nig = $row['night'];
```

Comment: explode по -. Но при таком хранении данных могут быть большие проблемы, когда сами названия содержат тире. вы не сможете отличить тире в названии от разделителя частей маршрута

Comment: Я эти пробелы могу убрать, но не пойму как это реализовать.

Comment: Так пробелы то это скорее польза, чем вред, если они всегда есть. может это и есть тот признак, который позволит разбить строку. `explode(' - ', $row['route_long_name'])` даст вам массив из двух элементов, собственно первой и второй остановки

Comment: спасибо я уже понял, а как вывести допустим результат, только Array[0] =>"Test" по ключу, а не выводить Array[1] =>"Test1"

Comment: хм. так вы же сами решаете что печатать, а что нет, print $array[0]

Comment: спасибо разобрался